# How to set vscode terminal charset(for decoding) to GBK, or set vscode gcc build task use "-fexec-charset=UTF-8"

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, vscode-tasks, charset

When i use the button "run C/c++ file" to run a ".c" file, and i got wrong characters in my terminal(default by powershell).

1. all is on windows 11
2. the .c file is utf-8 format
3. after run task finished, i inputed "chcp" in the named "cppdbg" terminal, and i got "65001"(UTF-8), so i gusses the ordinary outputs is encoded by "936"(GBK).

in other words, the ordinary outputs is encoded by "936"(GBK) and the "cppdbg" terminal decode with "65001"(UTF-8), so they are not matched correctly.

I know there is two ways to fix this problem:

1. Set "gcc" to complile with arg "-fexec-charset=UTF-8", then i set it in task.json like

```json
"args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-fexec-charset=UTF-8",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ]
```

but it does not work. and i use gcc to compile and link directly rather than using the vscode button "run C/c++ file", Nodoubtedly it works.

2. Set the "cppdbg" terminal decoding to "936", i tred to set it in setting.json like

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": ["-NoExit","\C","chcp 936"]
        }
}
```

but it also does not work, "chcp 936" executed absolutely, but there is something hided in the button "run C/c++ file",  still show wrong character and input "chcp" will get "65001" not "936"

Finally i use a extension named "code runner", and set gcc arg "-fexec-charset=UTF-8", it works,and  i want to know why both solution 1 and 2 which i mentioned above are not work.

Comment: -fexec-charset=utf-8 is the default, you don't need to specify it explicitly. Please post a [mcve], it is unclear what exactly works and what doesn't.

Comment: I just tried to use printf("%s",str);  to print ```vvxpwojawzgdcyadsixgejswpigmihlbcjngbqiagwxflsfmvexayzfodfdriwzmjtjlyiggardqzillpbcikeyadpvrianovwbmccsvmekwiaqglhguepxwnscmfgjzmielloxzfhkossrnsvfkwndsnzdwnqmwkhwoxyjjzexenlnydzqvrcv```,  and i see there is some letters are displayed incorrectly in terminal.  Thanks, you reminded me "-fexec-charset=utf-8 is the default"，and undid modification in the code runner extention,  it is  increditable the terminal can display this string just now,  maybe code runner had did some modification for me.

Comment: All of this is ASCII and should print no matter what. Or am I missing something? This is why [mcve] is important. Takes the guessing out of the picture.